# Taking url from XML and making Javascript hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, hyperlink, jquery-events

I've got a task I need to complete for an interview and I'm having issues with one annoying part. I have to create a portfolio site that displays 8 images at a time on the front page. These images need to be hyperlinks.

All the data I need (image location, url, title etc) is stored in an XML file. I've got all this data out and have successfully created a pagination Javascript animation that displays 8 images on a page with their relevant title.

What I'm struggling to do is make the images into hyperlinks, I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but every time I try and add the hyperlinks it either stops displaying images or displays images but breaks the pagination and animation.

I've included the HTML, JS and CSS below, obviously given I haven't attached the XML you won't be able to see anything. I'm hoping some will know how to do this though!

Let me know if the XML is required..

http://jsfiddle.net/gFg56/1/ `-` Code

What its meant to look like with the images on the front page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#portfolio-item').append('<li><a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + image + '" alt="' + title + '"></a></li>');
```

If it doesn't, can you post the error you get?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Do the images need to be hyperlinks really or just behave like them? Isn't the issue here based on the fact that you have to prevent the default behaviour of the hyperlink so you can handle the rendering in JavaScript and perhaps navigate to the linked URL using JavaScript?